# ImportError: cannot import name 'Chromedriver' from 'selenium' error using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to automate some day-to-day tasks using python on my Mac. I am somewhat of a beginner and I have browsed for hours trying to find a solution to this problem. I am trying to import chromedriver from selenium but I keep getting the same error. I have tried relocating the chromedriver and downloading selenium over again but still no results

This is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import Chromedriver

PATH = "/Applications/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
 driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mikaelanwar/Desktop/mything.py", line 2, in <module>
    from selenium import Chromedriver
ImportError: cannot import name 'Chromedriver' from 'selenium' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/__init__.py)
```

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: uh, i beileve that, in most of scene, actually  it is not need to use selenium to simulate the user. For example, if you want to get the result after clicking an button, you can send the post request in python rather than click the button, because the function of clicking of the button always is send the post requset. So, you can try to change your way to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to import `Chromedriver`. Importing `webdriver` or importing `Chrome` will serve your purpose.

---

### Solution

There are two solutions to this issue:

- First approach:

  - Remove both the imports and import only `Chrome` from `selenium.webdriver` as follows:

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

    PATH = "/Applications/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
    ```
- Second approach:

  - Remove the import:

    ```
    from selenium import Chromedriver
    ```
  - Import `webdriver` from *Selenium*:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    ```
  - Effective code block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver

    PATH = "/Applications/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
    ```

---

### Update

As per [Python bindings for Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/):
Supported python bindings are:

- Python :: 2.7
- Python :: 3.4
- Python :: 3.5
- Python :: 3.6

Additionally in the discussion [Selenium 3 is incompatible with Python 3.9](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8762) @AutomatedTester clearly [mentioned](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8762#issuecomment-704882117):

> We won't be releasing another version 3 as we're heading to finishing off Selenium 4. It is a drop in replacement to use Selenium 4.0.0.a5 so should work the same. There should not be any breaking changes.

---

### Solution

The easiest solution seems to use either:

- *Selenium v4.x*
- *Python v3.6*

Comment: I have just tried the first approach but I am getting another error that states that webdriver is not defined. I would really appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem please.

Comment: @micky What error do you see? How about the second approach?

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mikaelanwar/Desktop/mything.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined'

Comment: I tried the second approach of importing webdriver which did not work. I do not understand when you say to remove the import.

Comment: @micky Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I have installed selenium 4 by using: pip3 install selenium==4.0.0.a7. Am I supposed to leave the code as it is or modify it?

Comment: @micky Selenium `selenium==4.0.0.a7` being a _alpha_ release I'm still with `selenium==3,x` so won't comment from that perspective.